# Scraping File Paths from GitHub Repo yields 400 Response, but viewing in browser works fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I’m trying to scrape all the file paths from links like this: https://github.com/themichaelusa/Trinitum/find/master, without using the GitHub API at all.

The link above contains a data-url attribute in the HTML (table, id=‘tree-finder-results’, class=‘tree-browser css-truncate’), which is used to make a URL like this: https://github.com/themichaelusa/Trinitum/tree-list/45a2ca7145369bee6c31a54c30fca8d3f0aae6cd

which displays this dictionary:

```
{"paths":["Examples/advanced_example.py","Examples/basic_example.py","LICENSE","README.md","Trinitum/AsyncManager.py","Trinitum/Constants.py","Trinitum/DatabaseManager.py","Trinitum/Diagnostics.py","Trinitum/Order.py","Trinitum/Pipeline.py","Trinitum/Position.py","Trinitum/RSU.py","Trinitum/Strategy.py","Trinitum/TradingInstance.py","Trinitum/Trinitum.py","Trinitum/Utilities.py","Trinitum/__init__.py","setup.cfg","setup.py"]}
```

when you view it in a browser like Chrome. However, GET request yields a `<[400] Response>`.

Here is the code I used:

```
username, repo = ‘themichaelusa’, ‘Trinitum’
ghURL = 'https://github.com'
url = ghURL + ('/{}/{}/find/master'.format(self.username, repo))
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
repoContent = soup.find('div', class_='tree-finder clearfix')
fileLinksURL = ghURL + str(repoContent.find('table').attrs['data-url'])
filePaths = requests.get(fileLinksURL)
print(filePaths)
```

Not sure what is wrong with it. My theory is that the first link creates a cookie that allows the second link to show the file paths of the repo we are targeting. I'm just unsure how to achieve this via code. Would really appreciate some pointers!

Comment: did you note `Examples/advanced_example.py` is not relative to `https://github.com/themichaelusa/Trinitum/find/master` but `https://github.com/themichaelusa/Trinitum/blob/master` ?

Comment: My advice is to use the developper tools of the browser to carefully control what requests are actually sent, print `url` and `fileLinksURL` and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a go. The links containing `.py` files are generated dynamically, so to catch them you need to use selenium. I think this is what you expected.

```
from selenium import webdriver ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = 'https://github.com/themichaelusa/Trinitum/find/master'
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
driver.quit()
for link in soup.select('#tree-finder-results .js-tree-finder-path'):
    print(urljoin(url,link['href']))
```

Partial results:

```
https://github.com/themichaelusa/Trinitum/blob/master
https://github.com/themichaelusa/Trinitum/blob/master/Examples/advanced_example.py
https://github.com/themichaelusa/Trinitum/blob/master/Examples/basic_example.py
https://github.com/themichaelusa/Trinitum/blob/master/LICENSE
https://github.com/themichaelusa/Trinitum/blob/master/README.md
https://github.com/themichaelusa/Trinitum/blob/master/Trinitum/AsyncManager.py
```